# Change computer name Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

When I connect to Linux 18  I get this 
name@server-Belkin ~>
How can I remove "name"? and change it to other name

Comment: The format is username@hostname:current-working-directory, so that is probably the username you chose.

Comment: yeah a now but i want change the username

Comment: Change the username everywhere? Or just change the prompt string in terminal?

Comment: i wante to change name everywhere , i find to change hostname but i  don t find how to change user name

Comment: @john Ubuntu, or Lubuntu? Please click [edit] and remove the tag if it's Ubuntu; if it's really Lubuntu you are using, please update the subject line accordingly.

Comment: Linux 18 = mint. Not Ubuntu. Did you mean 18.04?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**COMPUTER NAME CHANGE**

First, run `sudo hostnamectl | grep hostname` and confirm that's the name of the PC you want to change.

Next, run `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname whatever` where *whatever* is the name you wish to use henceforth.

Confirm the change was effective with `sudo hostnamectl | grep hostname`  to see the change was effective.

When I check the [man page for hostnamectl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hostnamectl.1.html), I can't see if it require elevated priveleges, so you may be able to do it without the *sudo*.

**USER NAME CHANGE**

Set the "root" account password with `sudo passwd root` then log out with `exit` and log in using the "root" account and the password you just set.

Change the username and the home folder to the new name that you want with
 `usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>`

Return the root account to its usual unreachability with `passwd -l root` then logout with `exit`.

Login with your new username.